# How to display a Toast only if a row is been deleted in ROOM Database?

Tags: android, android-room

I want to display a Toast only if a row is Successfully been deleted from ROOM database and also when deletion is not successful.

Row is successfully being deleted but i want to display Toast on both successful and unsuccessfull situations.

MainActivity

```
String enroll = et_enroll.getText().toString().trim();
                MainActivity.studentDatabase.daoAccess().deleteStudent(enroll);
```

Dao File

```
@Query("Delete from Student where enroll like :enrollment")
    void deleteStudent(String enrollment);
```

Display Toast on both success and unsuccessful deletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Query("Delete from Student where enroll like :enrollment")
void deleteStudent(String enrollment);

Change return type of method "deleteStudent" to int.
i.e:
@Query("Delete from Student where enroll like :enrollment")  
int deleteStudent(String enrollment); 

This will return number of rows affected.So if number of rows affected > 0 deletion 
is success or is failed.
```

////

```
String enroll = et_enroll.getText().toString().trim();
int rows_affected = MainActivity.studentDatabase.daoAccess().deleteStudent(enroll);

if (rows_affected > 0) {
Toast.makeText(Delete.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} else {

Toast.makeText(Delete.this, "Unsuccessfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

\\

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it on a `try-catch`:

```
try {
  MainActivity.studentDatabase.daoAccess().deleteStudent(enroll);
  Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (SQLException e) {
  Toast.makeText(context, "Delete failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Exception 'java.sql.SQLException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block

Comment: Try to make it generic, try to catch `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  MainActivity.studentDatabase.daoAccess().deleteStudent(enroll);
  Toast.makeText(context, "Student Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Toast.makeText(context, "Student Deletion failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```